# Xiaomi phones, this app was built for an older version

Tags: android, google-play-console, xiaomi

The error `this app was built for an older version` only shows for `Xiaomi` phones. All other androids can download and use the app without any issues.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Localizations | 92 localizations |
| Permissions | 21 permissions |
| Features | 13 features |
| API levels | 21+ |
| Target SDK | 29 |

Comment: I'm also facing the same behavior here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76016486/play-store-fails-to-detect-device-compatibility

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meanwhile?

Comment: @user2342558 I'm rebuilding the whole app with the latest dependencies